# Is it possible to trigger a page refresh from an api route in next js?

Tags: next.js

When my route /api/example is invoked, I want my /test/page.tsx to get refreshed and fetch new data.

I want this to happen automatically while the user is on that page without them having to refresh it.

I think this would be possible with websockets, but was wondering if next js provides this functionality some how?